# How can I change the 'label' in my chart.js when selecting a different option in Javascript and HMTL?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to have the 'label' that is used in the datasets from Chart.js (version 3.5.1) update whenever a different

<select

<option<>

is selected from HTML.

I tried doing a function in javascript to try to update that label, but I am failing to do so and I cannot find anything online that could help me.

Here is my code:

```js
 const data = {
        labels: ['Miami', 'Chicago', 'New York', 'Los Angeles', 'London', 'Paris'],
        datasets: [
            {
                //label: genDate,
                data: [
                    2000,
                    1500,
                    1000,
                    3000,
                    950,
                    600
                ],
                backgroundColor: ['red',
                    'green',
                    'yellow',
                    'blue',
                    'orange',
                    'purple'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data,
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    };
     function showGraph() {
        var x = document.getElementById("hideButton");
        var graph = document.getElementById("container");
        if (graph.style.display === "none" && x.style.display === "none")
        {
            x.style.display = "block";
            graph.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    const changeMyChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
    );
    function updateTitle(chartName) {
        changeMyChart.config.data.datasets.label = chartName
        changeMyChart.update();
    }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="card w-75 mt-2">
            <div class="card-header p-2 d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center">
                <h2>Generate Sales Report</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body p-2 d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center">
                <div class="form-group mr-1">
                    <label for="packageType" class="form-text text-white ml-4"><b>Select Package Type</b></label>
                <select id="packageType" class="custom-select m-1">
                    <option value="0">Select Package Type</option>
                    <option value="Air" onclick="updateTitle('Air')">Air</option>
                    <OPTION value="Cruise" onclick="updateTitle('Cruise')">Cruise</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="Ground" onclick="updateTitle('Ground')">Ground</OPTION>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ml-2">
                    <label for="year" class="form-text text-white ml-4"><b>Select Year</b></label>
                <select class="custom-select m-1" id="year">
                    <option value="0">Select Year</option>
                    <option value="2022" onclick="updateTitle('2022')">2022</option>
                    <OPTION value="2021" onclick="updateTitle('2021')">2021</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="2020" onclick="updateTitle('2020')">2020</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="2019" onclick="updateTitle('2019')">2019</OPTION>
                    <Option value="2018" onclick="updateTitle('2018')">2018</Option>
                    <Option value="2017" onclick="updateTitle('2017')">2017</Option>
                    <Option value="2016" onclick="updateTitle('2016')">2016</Option>
                    <Option value="2015" onclick="updateTitle('2015')">2015</Option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ml-2">
                    <label for="quarter" class="form-text text-white ml-4"><b>Select Financial Quarter</b></label>
                <select class="custom-select m-1" id="quarter">
                    <option value="0">Select Financial Quarter</option>
                    <option value="1" onclick="updateTitle('Quarter 1')">Quarter 1</option>
                    <OPTION value="2" onclick="updateTitle('Quarter 2')">Quarter 2</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="3" onclick="updateTitle('Quarter 3')">Quarter 3</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="4" onclick="updateTitle('Quarter 4')">Quarter 4</OPTION>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer p-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showGraph()">Generate Report</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container bg-white" id="container" style="display: none">
        <canvas id="myChart" style="margin: 50px 50px"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn btn-success justify-content-center" id="hideButton" onclick="hideGraph()" style="display: none; margin-top: 25px;">Hide Report</button>
    </div>
```

What I want to know is how I can make those values resemble into my chart.js "label" so everytime I update it with a different one, my chart displays the label that matches the options that were selected.

I apologize for the long code, the lines that are most important in the javascript are the updateTitle function and in HTML is the select and option tags.

Comment: when I pick different options, the chart doesn't change.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland What do you mean? Where?

Comment: when I run your code snippet, nothing changes no matter what I pick

Comment: @ChrisStrickland Are you talking about the graph? Yes, that is my question. I don't know how to manipulate that data. I want to start off with the 'label', from there I think I can pick it up on my own.

Comment: ok, let me think.  I'm not sure you have it set up quite right.  The label adjust shouldn't be in the onclick for the buttons, it should be in the chart update function.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland Of course I don't lol, that is why I am asking haha . Take your time